# How to create and save images with more than 3 channels in openCV

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have a 2d array of a dimension of 19X30000 where each row of dimension 1X30000 represents a signal. Each of these rows will be converted to their spectrograms later. What I want to do is to generate an image file with 19 channels where each layer will represent the spectrogram of the rows in the initial 2d array. So far, I have successfully generated 19 spectrograms and are stored them in a list now.

```
def makeSpec(row):
spec,freq,t,im = plt.specgram(row,Fs=100,NFFT=100,noverlap=50)
plt.axis('off')
figure = plt.gcf()
figure.set_size_inches(12, 1)

figure.canvas.draw()
img = np.array(figure.canvas.buffer_rgba())
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)

b = figure.axes[0].get_window_extent()
img = np.array(figure.canvas.buffer_rgba())
img = img[int(b.y0):int(b.y1),int(b.x0):int(b.x1),:]
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)

return img
```

---

```
    eeg = np.load('data/c2_ar/'+filename) #2d array

    images = []

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    images = pool.map(makeSpec, [row for row in eeg])

    pool.close()
```

How do I stitch all of them into a single 19 channeled images ( in the list 'images') which I can later use for training CNN which expects a 19 channeled input?

Comment: Just for clarification: You can store your 19 spectrograms inside some 3D NumPy array with dimensions `[..., 19]`. At runtime, you can pass that NumPy array to any function, method, etc. But, you won't be able to save an "image" with that dimensions. Why do you need an "image" here?

Comment: I need to save the images so that I can use them later for training my CNN. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Training CNNs doesn't necessarily means you need images!? Do you already have such a CNN which consumes "19 channeled input"? Do you have exemplary data to show? If you simply build "19 channeled" tensors for your CNN, you could save 19 images per initial array!? Apart from that, maybe it's possible to save a TIFF with 19 "pages" using OpenCV (or any other library)!? I'd suggest to clarify the actual input architecture of your CNN, before generating input data.

Comment: I am very new to this. Can you explain this further? Are you saying I can train my CNN which takes a 19 channeled input directly on a NumPy array?

Comment: I'm not working with CNNs at all, but yes, you can feed "anything" to CNNs: 1D signals, images, multi-dimensional data. It all depends on your architecture. I guess, you should have a thorough look at the fundamentals of CNNs, and go through some tutorials (and not only the ones using images!) before starting a "real" project like the described.